# codeigniter: how to handle unwanted result in error url ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a new CI developer dealing with security issues in one web site.

I have a url like:

```
http://myweburl/Everything/gov/2
```

which '2' indicates the parameter to query db.

Here is my question:
If someone navigates following url:

```
http://myweburl/Everything/gov/2/order.txt
```

Actually nothing in the url, but..he will get an empty result page.(with reply 200 OK)

This is not what I wanted. 
I hope he'll get a 404 error or something else to tell users that nothing in the url.

Can anyone please give me some clues how to achieve my goal?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which one is your controller? `Everything`?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Your controller is `Everything`, your function is `gov` and `2` is your segment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my question well.
Everything -> controller
gov -> function
2 -> parameter segment

Comment: It's all good. My answer should help you. (I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you only want to show a valid page if their is the correct number URI segments in the URL that represents a parameter in the query.

You should check the number of `URI segments` as a pre-process before calling any other methods. This way you can be sure that there is in fact only 1 segment in the URL

If you find that there exists more than 3 segments in your `URL`, then handle that situation accordingly with the convenient functions that CodeIgniter offers such [Error Handling.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

You can check for the correct number of segments in the URL, and if it not what you want it to be, then call the `show_404()` method.

In the example URL you posted:
`http://myweburl/Everything/gov/2/order.txt` , there is actually 4 segments.

```
    // from the docs http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

     $total_segments = $this->uri->total_segments();

    // 3 segments would be the max if this is your url:
    // http://myweburl/Everything/gov/2/order.txt (this url contains 4 segments)
    //                 ^controller/function/uri_segment
    // this means that there are 3 segments in your URL
    // you don't want to have more than 3, so check for that
    // with the total_segments() function

     if($total_segments > 3)

     {
           $valid = false;
           show_404();

     }

     else 

     {

          $valid = true;

     }

     if($valid) 

     {

     // process data as usual

     }
```